# Directx 9 - is the SetScissorRect behavior same for surfaces?

Tags: c++, graphics, directx, rendering, directx-9

First off, i need to use directx 9 for compatibility,

i started drawing a text with

```
RECT pos { 2, 2, 100, 100 };


if(!gfont)
    D3DXCreateFont( iDev, 20, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, DEFAULT_CHARSET, NULL, ANTIALIASED_QUALITY, NULL, "Segoe UI Light", &gfont );
else
{
    gfont->DrawText( NULL, "Sample", -1, &pos, NULL, D3DCOLOR_ARGB( 255, 0, 255, 255 ) );
}
```

and it's all right, i get:

[image]

so if we add `SetScissorRect`

```
RECT protectedRect { 2, 2, 50, 50 };

iDev->SetRenderState( D3DRS_SCISSORTESTENABLE, TRUE );  
iDev->SetScissorRect( &protectedRect );
```

i get:

[image]

which it's the right result, now if i do with surfaces, the surface it's loaded with `D3DXLoadSurfaceFromFile()` and allocated with `CreateOffscreenPlainSurface()` from a jpg file...

```
iDev->GetBackBuffer(NULL, NULL, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &backBuffsfc);
iDev->UpdateSurface(sfc, NULL, backBuffsfc, NULL);

RECT protectedRect { 2, 2, 50, 50 };

iDev->SetRenderState( D3DRS_SCISSORTESTENABLE, TRUE );  
iDev->SetScissorRect( &protectedRect );
```

the surface keeps appearing completely like

[image]

the question is, why is not clipped like the text?

Comment: Well, you set ScissorRect after copying image into backbuffer.

Comment: yes, exactly... if more code it's need, i can add...

Comment: Setting scissor rectangle after drawing does nothing since backbuffer is already filled. It will only effect subsequent drawing operations, if any. So you should put it prior to UpdateSurface call

Comment: @user7860670 same results, keeps appearing completely... everything it's being called inside of `BeginScene()` then `Render()`, and finally `EndScene()` and `Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)`...

Comment: On the second thought, UpdateSurface is probably not a normal rendering operation, it is just a memory copy that bypasses rendering pipeline and therefore scissor rect clipping may not work on it. However you can directly provide clipping source rectangle as a second parameter when calling `UpdateSurface`. `DrawText` probably works by normally rendering some textured quads.

Comment: if i do https://rextester.com/TVYR28229, i get https://i.imgur.com/LAct13w.png ... maybe if i change it to texture, it might work...

Comment: That's expected, since you clear backbuffer inside of scissor rectangle.

Comment: @user7860670 the only problem is i need to do it like this, since i need to be able to make a scroll slide with images... anyway i'm gonna try another method, thanks.

Comment: @user7860670 apparently as i suspected, converting the surface to a sprite, i was able to draw text over, and clip it correctly :)   https://i.imgur.com/63Bm65l.png